# Centre of mass in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, observers

In the paper from [Costa 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6443), Figure 1, it discusses how the velocity of an observer influences where the center of mass of a spinning object is measured.

If an observer is moving with velocity $v$ opposite to the rotation of the object, then the points on one side of the body will be seen to be moving faster than points on the other side. **This argument I understand**.

The next argument is that therefore one side of the body is more massive than the other and so the center of mass will shift to the heavier side. Can someone explain why this should be true? **If the points on one side of the body are moving faster than the other, how does this correspond to one side being more massive?**

Comment: I haven't read the paper, but this sounds like it's just the heuristic of relativistic mass. BTW, the abstract says it's about GR, but your question seems to me to be about SR.